# Reading XLS in Matlab with header as handle

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, xls, xlsread

I have an **xls** file which I am reading inside MATLAB:

```
 my_data = xlsread(filename,'worksheet_name','B:B');
```

Above command gives me all the content of column B into vector `my_data`.
The first row of column B is a header [type string: Lets call it `my_header` ].

Now I wish to do it like this instead

1. Open workbook (filename) and go to worksheet 'worksheet_name'
2. Search for column having header as `my_header`
3. Pass all contents under that column into the matlab vector variable
4. I have to repeat this for another column in the same worksheet and for multiple work sheets in the same workbook.

Can someone provide the most efficient code to handle this ?
My present approach uses hard-coded column numbers which is very dirty

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The easiest way will be to read the whole workbook and try to find the column you want with a `for` loop and [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), then copy the correct column to a new variable

Comment: Yeah, I agree to your suggestion. I was thinking if there was a built in matlab function to handle it that would be awesome :P Thanks anyways.